# how to convert date string(2016/5/7/ 4:25:00 PM) to date format to (2016-05-07 4:25:00) in python

Tags: python, datetime

having trouble converting this string into a datetime this is what I tried so far in code:

```
import datetime

mystring = '2016/5/7/  4:25:00 PM'
dateobj = datetime.datetime.strptime(mystring, "%Y-%B-%dT%H:%M:%S-%H:%M")
print (dateobj)
```

it throws me errors and I search in the library and still can't figure it out what I have wrong in my format.
Please any help I'll gratly apreciate it

Comment: yea I am sorry I'll doble check before posting they are non related they were just example and its edited :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as:

```
import datetime    
mystring = '2016/5/7 4:25:00 PM'


dateobj = datetime.datetime.strptime(mystring, "%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p")

dateobj
Out[1]: datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 7, 16, 25)

dateobj1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(mystring, "%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S")

dateobj1
Out[2]: '2016-05-07 04:25:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that in order to convert a date object you first have to create a date object. This means that your formatting will have to match the current string format `'2016/5/7 4:25:00 PM' = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S %p"`. So we can now create a date obj and then format it using `strftime` with your new format `"%Y-%B-%dT%H:%M:%S-%H:%M"`.

```
import datetime

mystring = '2016/5/7 4:25:00 PM'
dateobj = datetime.datetime.strptime(mystring, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S %p")
dateobj = datetime.datetime.strftime(dateobj, "%Y-%B-%dT%H:%M:%S-%H:%M")
print (dateobj)
```

the output recieved is a little funky, but it matches your format perfectly. Visit the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) library to view the format codes and read up on `strptime` vs `strftime`. Good luck.

> Output: 2016-May-07T04:25:00-04:25

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where your format string came from, but it's wrong. It doesn't match your string format at all.

Take a look at the [available options in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

You want this:

```
dateobj = datetime.datetime.strptime(mystring, "%Y/%m/%d/ %I:%M:%S %p")
```

This will get you a date object. You can then do this to reformat it how you want:

```
dateobj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S")
```

---

A couple things that were wrong with yours:

- You used `%H` twice. This resulted in an error saying it'd be redefined.
- `%B` is full month name (ie. January). You have a numeral.
- The `-`s are incorrect since you have `/`s.
- The `T` is not in your string at all.

Answer (score 0):

Easily with `dateutil.parser.parse`

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> d = parse('2016/5/7/  4:25:00 PM')
>>> d.strftime("%Y-%B-%dT%H:%M:%S-%H:%M")
'2016-May-07T16:25:00-16:25'
>>> d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S")
'2016-05-07 04:25:00'
```